# How to make a script that copies files from different subject folders?

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm having trouble setting up a script that copies and converts files. What I basically want is a script that takes a subject e.g.

```
folder/subjects/subject_name/mri/norm.mgz
```

copies this file into

```
folder/investigation_folder/fs_norms/subject_name/
```

and converts the `norm.mgz` to `norm.nii` using  `mri_convert`, and does this with +300 subjects (in the subjects folder).

This should be fairly simple... Can anybody help me out here?

I'm a big newb! This is a example of what i would like to do - with a single subject:

```
mkdir /mnt/projects/Project_folder/thalamic_subnuclei/fs_norms/gXXX/

cp /mnt/projects/Project_folder/subjects/gXXX/mri/norm.mgz /mnt/projects/Project_folder/thalamic_subnuclei/fs_norms/gXXX/

mri_convert mnt/projects/Project_folder/thalamic_subnuclei/fs_norms/gXXX/norm.mgz mnt/projects/Project_folder/thalamic_subnuclei/fs_norms/gXXX/norm.nii
```

All my subjects are called g followed by 3-4 numbers. Now I need to set up a loop that does this with the +300 subjects in the `/mnt/projects/Project_folder/subjects/` folder.

Comment: You are probably right about the simplicity.  Will you edit your question snow us how far you've gotten and where you're stuck?  A script is a simple list of commands.  Write down each command when performing the steps on one file.  Then put the commands in a [loop](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html).  If you get stuck, we'll help you to fix your script, but we need to know where you are stuck.

Comment: See https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/mri_convert for `mri_convert`'s syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how the FOR loop can be applied within a bash script to solve this task:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Execute do-done inner part for each "item" under "folder/subjects/"
for subject in folder/subjects/*
do
    # Check whether the source file exists
    if [[ -f ${subject}/mri/norm.mgz ]]
    then
        # ${subject##*/} will cut the parent path from the value of the variable '$subject'
        echo "Processing: ${subject##*/}"

        # Create the new subject directory
        mkdir -p "folder/investigation_folder/fs_norms/${subject##*/}"

        # Copy the .mgz file into the new directory
        cp "${subject}/mri/norm.mgz" "folder/investigation_folder/fs_norms/${subject##*/}/"

        # Do the conversion to .nii (I'm not sure this is the correct syntax of mri_convert that you are using)
        mri_convert "folder/investigation_folder/fs_norms/${subject##*/}/norm.mgz" "folder/investigation_folder/fs_norms/${subject##*/}/norm.nii"
    fi
done
```